# JsDoc for function returning a class

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I was coding some JavaScript modules trying to have the intellisense working on VsCode with the JsDocs.

But now I'm struggling trying to write the JsDoc for the following case:

Suppose I have this classes

```js
class SomeClass extends Array {}
class SomeOtherClass extends String {}
```

And I want to create this function to extend them

```js
function WithFeature(base) {
  return class extends base {
    constructor() {
      super(...arguments)
    }
    feature(){
      // do something...
    }
  }
}
```

So I can make more cool classes

```js
class CoolClass extends WithFeature(SomeClass) {
  // ...
}

class OtherCoolClass extends WithFeature(SomeOtherClass) {
  // ...
}
```

How can I JsDoc my beautiful `WithFeature`?

I thought something like this would have worked

```js
/**
 * @template {T}
 * @param {new () => T} base 
 * @returns {new () => T}
 */
function WithFeature(base) {
  // ...
}
```

or maybe this

```
/** @type {<T>(base: T) => new () => T} */
function WithFeature(base) {
// ...
```

But of course it didn't work for me (ie. it didn't show the intellisense hints on VsCode) otherwise I wouldn't have asked this question!

Have anybody else encountered the same drama?

---

### Edit

I noticed the following, which can be a step towards the solution!

```js
class SomeClass extends Array {}
class SomeOtherClass extends String {}

/**
 * @template T
 * @returns {T}
 */
function WithFeature(/** @type {T} */ base) {
  return class extends base {
    feature(){
      // do something...
    }
  }
}

class CoolClass extends WithFeature(SomeClass) {
  // I can type ctrl-space to see the properties and methods
  // from the SomeClass (and from Array) but not from WithFeature
}

class OtherCoolClass extends WithFeature(SomeOtherClass) {
  // I can type ctrl-space to see the properties and methods
  // from the SomeOtherClass (and from String) but not from WithFeature
}
```

But still I couldn't find a way to see the hints of `WithFeature` (ie. the `feature()=>void` method)

I also tried `/** @returns {{feature()=>void} & T} */` but still VsCode is showing me only the properties from the `T` type but not the new `feature` method from `WithFeature`

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add the right constrain on the template and the hints worked.

The following code is the case of the example in the question with the correct JsDoc and some other stuff to play with.

```js
class SomeClass extends Array {
  foo() {
    return "" + this
  }
}

class SomeOtherClass extends String {
  bar() {}
  constructor(/**@type {SomeClass}*/ obj) {
    super(obj.foo())
  }
}

/**
 * @template {new (...args:any[]) => any} T
 */
function WithFeature(/** @type {T} */ base) {
  return class extends base {
    constructor(){
      super(...arguments)
      console.log(`featured ${this.constructor.name || base.name}`)
    }
    feature(/**@type {String}*/x){
      // do something...
      console.log(x)
    }
  }
}
```

Now the hints are working (almost) as expected

```js
class CoolClass extends WithFeature(SomeClass) {
  // Hitting ctrl-space shows all the properties and methods
  // from WithFeatureType (ie the feature method), SomeClass (the foo method)
  // and all the properties and method from Array

  foo() {
    return super.foo() // typing "super." I can find the foo method
  }

  feature(/**@type {String}*/x) {
    super.feature(x) // typing "super." I can find the feature method too
    super.length // and there are also hints for all the properties of Array
  }
}

class OtherCoolClass extends WithFeature(SomeOtherClass) {
  constructor() {
    // here vscode shows the correct hints from the Array constructor
    const data = new (WithFeature(CoolClass))(1,2,3)

    // when I type the "()" the IDE shows the correct hints
    // from the String constructor
    super(data)

    // writing "this." the shows the correct hints too, Hurrah!
    this.feature("hola") 

    // strange enough when I type
    // this.feature(this) // without a "jsdoc double casting" as below
    // the IDE complains about the type of "this" not being compatible
    // with "String" but SomeOtherClass extends string so
    // the WithFeature version should too
    this.feature(/**@type {String}*/(/**@type {unknown}*/ (this)))
    // but it does the same with "this.feature(new SomeOtherClass())"
    // so I think that is the IDE that is wrong here
  }
}
```

---

##### To conclude

The JsDoc for function returning a class is just

```
/**
 * @template {new (...args:any[]) => any} T
 */
function MyGenericDecorator(/** @type {T} */ decorated) {
  // ...
  return class extends decorated {}
}
```

And the return type is decuded automatically